# Python: loop doing the same thing to one item n-times as opposed doing it once to n-items

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Here is the example:
I am trying to grab a series of XML pages, and then extract data from them.

It downloads each individual page, as the while loop was designed to do but the tester() function prints the data from the first file it downloads V number of times despite it downloading and clearing the file after each time it loops through.

This is killing me what am I doing wrong?

```
def tester():
    with open('raw.txt') as myFile:
        test = linecache.getline('raw.txt', 12)
        print test
        test = ""
        myFile.close

def grab_data(Year, rcvote):
    link = "XXX/%s/roll%s.xml" % (Year, rc)
    site = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    localFile = open('raw.txt', 'w')
    localFile.write(site.read(100000))
    localFile.close()
    tester()


while (V !=0):
    rc = str(V)
    if (len(rc) == 2):
        rc = "0%s" % (rc)
    elif (len(rc) == 1):
        rc = "00%s" % (rc)
    else:
        rc = rc
    grab_data(Year, rc)
    V = V - 1
```

Comment: More nitpicking: Why are you passing `rc` as `rcvote` to `grab_data` if you are using it directly?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, try this one-liner to convert `V` into a zero padded string: `rc = '%03d' % V`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the linecache module.  It assumes that same-named files are the same.

But why write the data to a file just to read it again anyway?

```
def tester(text):
    line12 = text.splitlines()[11]
    print line12

def grab_data(year, rcvote):
    link = "XXX/%s/roll%03d.xml" % (year, rcvote)
    site = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    tester(site.read(100000))

while v:
    grab_data(year, rc)
    v -= 1
```

Comment: I am new to python so I am not always making the best decisions.  What would be a better way?

Comment: Exactly. Also `linecache.checkcache()` will recheck cached files and remove them from cache if they changed on disk. But still using `linecache` makes little sense in this example. Why not read directly from files or url.

Comment: how about `for V in xrange(start, 0, -1):`?

Comment: Everyone's comments have been incredibly helpful.  Do y'all have any recommendations on what to read in order to learn more efficient coding?